# User registration app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, jdo

Is it possible to create my own users database for a google app engine app, so that it's not required for someone to have a google/openId account when he registers ?

Comment: It was a throwaway answer to a not-very-good question. There is no dependency on Google accounts for *users* of GAE apps, and login functionality can be developed in whatever framework you are most comfortable with.

Comment: See [Storing Data](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/storage).  Create an Entity called "User" with any properties you want.  But yes, the question is too broad and should initially show some coding effort by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you will need to write all utility methods for providing proper authentication for your users.  Rather than do this, I would recommending looking into the [authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html) services that [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com) can provide (Google acquired Firebase in 2014).  At the moment, it seems Firebase will become integrated into many Google Cloud Services.